# ABPersonViewController+delete

Tags: iphone, abpersonviewcontroller

Can anyone help me enable a delete button in `ABPersonViewController`?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at ABPersonViewController+Delete category which does not use any private methods:

https://github.com/shrtlist/ABDelete

Comment: this is the exact same thing as below and almost certainly uses a private API

Answer (score 0):

For me this code works:

```
ABPersonViewController *pvc = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
[pvc setPersonViewDelegate:self];
[pvc setAllowsEditing:YES];
[pvc setAllowsDeletion:YES];
[pvc setAllowsActions:YES];
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that his is a hidden method that may cause your app to be rejected from the App Store. Also, you should do a test before using the method (`if (pvc respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsDeletion:))`).

Comment: it results in compile error because setAllowsDeletion is a private method

Comment: I manage to get it working with     [picker setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"allowsDeletion"];. However, after delete, the windows doesn't pop up. There is no on delete delegate.

Comment: @JimThio please post here if you found out how to pop it up