# Delete button in ABPersonViewController in ios7

Tags: ios7, abpersonviewcontroller

I use an `ABPersonViewController` class to modify a contact.

In ios6 a could display the delete button at the end of the view, using the code:

```
[self.modContatto setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"allowsDeletion"];
```

In ios7 the same code has not effect and the delete button is not displayed.

There is a way in io7 to display the delete button?

Answer (score 1):

The method that you used before was a private method, and should have never been used. Apple could have rejected your app due to this. In iOS7, it is obviously no longer available. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847870/abpersonviewcontrollerdelete) for more information.  The actual [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPersonViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) don't allow either the deletion of contacts.